# Ansible AWX output showing partial result

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Am using Ansible AWX here. My playbook is trying to read the whole content from a file but the output only showing partial result (as shown below).

Anyone have any idea if it's possible to show the full result?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: See the little `...` just at the end of the truncated display of the message? What happens when you click there?

Comment: See also the `+` sign on top of your log display.

Comment: You may have a look into the Ansible Tower documentation about [Job Details - Playbook Run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/jobs.html#standard-output-view).